# use hour unit in pandas to_timedelta

Tags: python, pandas

From pandas document of pandas.to_timedelta(arg, box=True, unit='ns'), the unit has been explained as below:

```
unit of the arg (D,h,m,s,ms,us,ns) denote the unit, which is an integer/float number
```

So I think "h" should be means hours. but it seems I am wrong because below example doesn't work as expected:

```
import pandas as pd

base = pd.to_datetime("00:00", format="%H:%M")
print "base:",base
x = base + pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='s')
print "x:",x
y = base + pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='h')
print "y:",y
```

The output is:

```
base: 1900-01-01 00:00:00
x: 1900-01-01 00:00:01
y: 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
```

But I wish the y should be 01:00:00. what's correct way to use hour as unit?

Comment: That code seems to work for me (I get `y: 1900-01-01 01:00:00`).  What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am working on MacOSX, the pandas version is '0.14.0'.

Comment: Oh my god, really big bug! thanks for your help! I will upgrade pandas now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Moved from comments to close it:]

This was a bug, see [GH #7611](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7611), and was fixed for 0.14.1:

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.14.1'
>>> base = pd.to_datetime("00:00", format="%H:%M")
>>> base + pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='s')
Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:00:01')
>>> base + pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='h')
Timestamp('1900-01-01 01:00:00')
```